# English version of the Persian expression "the sunshine (sunlight) on the roof edge"

Tags: word-meaning, expressions, translation

There is an expression in Persian.

The translation of which is : "the sunshine (sunlight) on the roof edge";

and the meaning of which is : "the last beams of the sun when it's dusk".

Is there any related English expression for such meaning? ( I need it for a poem).

Comment: Is the "roof edge" the roof ridge?

Comment: You might try "the sunlight under the eaves."

Comment: "As the last sunlight of the day shown on the rooftop"? Anyway, I don't think there is a specific expression in English. I suppose English isn't so expressive regarding sunrise sunset words compared to other languages. I imagine it is a cultural thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific term that I am aware of, but "the last rays of the sun" or "the last rays of the day" suggest what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

No direct idiom that I'm aware of. You are free to use your own imagery in poems, indeed it is normally better to avoid idioms. The literal translation seems to be suitably "poetic" to me.